# Do not mutate state directly, Use setState() react/no-direct-mutation-state in React JS

Tags: reactjs, eslint

```
<input
  defaultValue={this.props.str.name}
  ref={(input) => { this.state.name = input; }}
  name="name"
  type="text"
  className="form-control"
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
/> 

handleInputChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  });
}

if(this.state.name.value === "") {
  this.msg.show('Required fields can not be empty', {
    time: 2000,
    type: 'info',
    icon: <img src="img/avatars/info.png" role="presentation"/>
  });
}
```

I'm trying to set the default value like that and wanted to access it as well. I did like this and accessed the value with `this.state.name.value` but the thing is its working but showing the warning as

> Do not mutate state directly, Use setState() 
>   react/no-direct-mutation-state .

Comment: Did you read the error? Do not modify the state object directly except for in the constructor, use `this.setState({ name: input });`

Comment: "But i used that thing if the user changes the value of the field"
handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    }

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Getting "Do not mutate state directly, Use setState()", Why?

Because, you are mutating the state value inside ref callback method to store the node ref, Here:

```
this.state.name = input;
```

---

**Solution:**

Don't use state variable to store the reference, You can directly store 
them in component instance because that will not change with time.

As per **[DOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)**:

> The state contains data specific to this component that may change
>   over time. The state is user-defined, and it should be a plain
>   JavaScript object.
>
> If you don’t use it in render(), it shouldn’t be in the state. For
>   example, you can put timer IDs directly on the instance.

Since you are using **[controlled input element](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)**, ref is not required. Directly use `this.state.name` with input element value property and `this.state.name` to access the value.

Use this:

```
<input
    value={this.state.name || ''}
    name="name"
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
    onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
/>
```

If you wanted to use `ref` then store the ref directly on instance, remove value property and you can remove the `onChange` event also, Use it like this:

```
<input
    ref={el => this.el = el}
    defaultValue={this.props.str.name}
    name="name"
    type="text"
    className="form-control"
/>
```

Now use this `ref` to access the value like this:

`this.el.value`

Answer (score 0):

you can instead clone the entire property value inside the with spread operator and then reform or edit the value for example :

```
state = {Counters: [{id:1,value:1},{id: 2,value: 2},{id: 3,value: 3},{id: 4,value: 4}]}
increment = (Counter) => {

        //This is where the state property value is cloned 

        const Counters = [...this.state.Counters];
        console.log(Counters);
        const index = Counters.indexOf(Counter)
        Counters[index].value++
        this.setState({
            Counters: this.state.Counters
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your line number 3 as

```
  ref={(input) => { this.setState({name: input}); }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining why this solves the OP's problem.