# Do not mutate state directly. Use setState() react/no-direct-mutation-state issue

Tags: reactjs

I am try to set user entered email,phone,username that exists from
database in login time and like to access the value with using
`onChange={(event)=>{this.state.emailId=event.currentTarget.value}}` but
I am getting issue. How to set State?

SignIN.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "../LoginPage/LoginPage.css"
import {auth} from "../firebase";

class SignIN extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            emailId : null,
            password: null
         }
    }

    login=()=>{
        // localStorage.setItem("users","admin");
        // window.location.reload();
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.emailId, this.state.password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in
                var user = userCredential.user;
                localStorage.setItem("users",JSON.stringify(user));
                window.location.reload();
                // ...
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //var errorCode = error.code;
               // var errorMessage = error.message;
            });
    }

    render() { 
        return ( 
        <div>
             <input className="logipage__text" onChange={(event)=>{this.state.emailId=event.currentTarget.value}} type="text" placeholder="Phone number, username, or email" />
             <input className="logipage__text" onChange={(event)=>{this.state.password=event.currentTarget.value}}  type="password" placeholder="Password" />
             <button className="login__button" onClick={this.login}>Log In</button>
        </div> 
    );
    }
}
 
export default SignIN;
```

I am getting issue below on these lines:

```
<input className="logipage__text" onChange={(event)=>{this.state.emailId=event.currentTarget.value}} type="text" placeholder="Phone number, username, or email" />
             <input className="logipage__text" onChange={(event)=>{this.state.password=event.currentTarget.value}}  type="password" placeholder="Password" />
             <button className="login__button" onClick={this.login}>Log In</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do not mutate state directly, Use setState() react/no-direct-mutation-state in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43691823/do-not-mutate-state-directly-use-setstate-react-no-direct-mutation-state-in-r)

Comment: I already use that way .but no effect in my code ,How to  set

Comment: `(event)=>{this.state.emailId=event.currentTarget.value}` no you don't.  Please read the answer carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this:

```
onChange={(event)=>{this.setState((prevState) => ({emailId: event.currentTarget.value, ...prevState}))}}
```

Read more about state here (for classes, in your case):
https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html